# Get all methods of an Interface or Abstract class using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How can I use reflection on an interface/abstract class to get all of its methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

E.g.,

```
MyInterfaceOrAbstractClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Comment: +1: This will give you its public methods.  You can use getMethod() to get all its methods (you may need to do this for parents as well.

Comment: @Peter, surely you meant the other way around

Comment: Thanks, this works :) Can this be done at runtime using interface name in a string?

Comment: @Rnet, yes you can use `Class.forName(..)`

Comment: @Johan, Sorry you are correct. getMethods gives all public methods. getDeclaredMethods() get all the methods for that class, but not the super classes.

Answer (score 6):

```
Class clazz = Something.class;
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    // do what you have to do with the method
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```